# Cannot get value back in VF page from the controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

I'm using the code below but I'm not able to get value in controller and also makes blank what I entered in VF page.

please check if this code needs correction:

VF Page:

```
<apex:InputText label="#Years in Existence:" value="{!inExistence}" id="iExistence" style="width:50px"/>
```

Controller:

```
public string inExistence {get; set;}

inExistence = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('iExistence');
```

Answer (score 1):

`{!...}` expressions automatically facilitate data transfers between the client and server. You typically use `ApexPages.currentPage().getparameters()` to read values from the URL query string.

In your controller, you simply need to access the variable:

```
System.debug(inExistence);
```

Comment: It works if I use like this in VF page: <input type="text" name = "iExistence" value="{!inExistence}" style="width:50px"/>

Comment: But it's not working by using InputText

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox, works fine with just using inExistence in the controller